# неизвестная ошибка в pyserial: SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)

Tags: python, windows, serial

Добрый день. Написал простой код с документации pyserial'а.
При запуске почему-то выдает ошибку.

Сам код:

```
import serial
import time

test = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600)
while(True):
    test.write(b'1')
    test.sleep(1)
    test.write(b'2')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/AdruinoTest/SendToARD.py", line 4, in <module>
    test = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600)
  File "H:\AdruinoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 31, in __init__
    super(Serial, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "H:\AdruinoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "H:\AdruinoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 62, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)
```

Comment: Как вариант можно попробовать зайти в диспетчер устройств и отключить данный порт, а потом обратно запустить. Возможно поможет

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105182/error-while-opening-port-in-python